# Docker run command in dockerfile executes only if dont specifiy a command on cli

Tags: docker

Say I have a Dockerfile:

```
.
.
RUN echo 'source /root/script.sh' >> /etc/bash.bashrc
```

(The script adds some env variables)

If I:

1) Do this:

```
docker run -it -v /home/user/script.sh:/root/script.sh image
```

It takes me to shell where if I call "env" I see the variable set by the script

But if I:

2) Do this:

```
docker run -it -v /home/user/script.sh:/root/script.sh image env
```

It prints out env and exits and my variable is missing

What am I missing? I need the variable to exists even if I specify a command/script like "env" at the end of the docker run command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run a command like

```sh
docker run ... image command
```

Docker *directly* runs the `command` you give; it doesn’t launch any kind of shell, and there’s no opportunity for a `.bashrc` or similar file to be read.

I’d suggest two things here:

1. If your program does need environment variables set in some form, set them directly using Dockerfile `ENV` directives.  Don’t try to edit `.bashrc` or `/etc/profile` or any other shell dotfile; they won’t reliably get run.
2. As much as you can install things in places so that you don’t need to change environment variables.  For instance, Python supports a “virtual environment” concept that allows an isolated library environment, which requires changing `$PATH` and similar things; but Docker provides the same isolation on its own, so just install things into the “global” package space.

If you really can’t manage either of these things, then you can write an entrypoint script that sets environment variables and then launches the container’s command.  This might look like

```sh
#!/bin/sh
. /root/script.sh
exec "$@"
```

And then you could include this in your Dockerfile like

```sh
...
COPY entrypoint.sh /
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["/app/myapp"]
```

(If you need to use `docker exec` to get a debugging shell in the container, that won’t be a child process of the entrypoint and won’t get its environment variables.)

Comment: Thank you. The "exec "$@"" was missing in my script.