# Docker - source .profile

Tags: docker

I have a script in which I export a few paths to the profile. This script is copied over in the Dockerfile. The issue is that the paths are not reflected when you run the container; it only gets reflected if you run `source .profile` in the `/root` folder in the container. I have `source .profile` in my script, too, but that doesn't seem to work. I'm new to Docker. How do I have it set up the moment the container runs, without the user having to `source .profile`?

Comment: [Docker run command in dockerfile executes only if dont specifiy a command on cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53659369/docker-run-command-in-dockerfile-executes-only-if-dont-specifiy-a-command-on-cli/53659805#53659805) asks a pretty similar question about why shell dotfiles don't work well in Docker; I have an answer there that lays out some alternatives.

Comment: Can you put the docker image in dockerhub ? Of course, without confidencial information, so we can reproduce it.

Answer (score 0):

**Use ENV values**.

ENV values are available to containers, but also RUN-style commands during the Docker build starting with the line where they are introduced.`

In docker file:

```
# no default value
ENV hey
# a default value
ENV foo /bar
# or ENV foo=/bar
```

Or if you are using the docker-compose you can use the .env file, if not you can also pass the --env-file arg to the docker run command.

```
env_var_name=another_value
```

Ref: [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env)

Other that the official way, you can do something like this:

```
ADD yourenvfile /tmp
RUN cat /tmp/yourenvfile >> /etc/environment
```

/etc/environment set the environment variables system wide.

Comment: I do have it set as an environment variable as shown above, I also have in my script file echo 'export...... '>>$HOME/.profile, I still have to do source .profile when the container runs for it to reflect the path

Comment: If you want to add a path to the PATH, then write it like this: ENV PATH="/the/path/I/want/to/add:${PATH}"

Comment: I don't understand why are you using a script to export the env in a docker image. Using one of the 3 alternatives I posted makes the env variables available to any program not necessarily invoked by shell unlike .bash_profile or .profile.

Comment: It's probably easier to just install stuff directly into `/usr/bin` (remember, isolated inside the image) than to try to modify `$PATH`.

Comment: Even if it's set as an environment variable, if I do echo it shows the path however I still need to do source .profile for it to actually run the commands in the .profile file. for example say if i try and do "make flash" for an esp32 it will give me an error "path/to/make/project.mk" no such file or directory. This is solved when I do source .profile in /root